# What is the correct usage of std::unique_ptr while pushing into std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

I want to have a vector of pointers to objects in my class. To avoid making a destructor for it I wanted to use `std::unique_ptr`, as the objects are created/owned/destructed in my class, but I have a compiler error I can't understand. Next code will serve as a short sample for my problem:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> createPtr(int value)
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(value));
    return ptr;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;
    vec.push_back(createPtr(1));

    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = createPtr(2);
    vec.push_back(ptr);//error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
}
```

Can you please explain me why I get this error and what is the correct usage for `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: What's the point of storing pointers to `int` instead of values in vector?

Comment: If you are contemplating `std::unique_ptr<>`, then you probably do *not* have a "vector of objects," but a "vector of pointers to objects." If you had a "vector of objects", then destruction would happen correctly automatically.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Please read the question

Comment: @Robᵩ I'll edit the question, I wanted to say pointers to obbjects

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider the `vec.push_back()`. It has two overloads which take either `const std::unique_ptr<int>&` or `std::unique_ptr<int>&&`. The first overload can **never be used**. This is because the `vector<>` requires the type to be assignable, or movable (C++11 addition). 'Assignability' implies copying. `push_back(const T&)` will try to copy (assign) the incoming value to the new space at the end of the container. `std::unique_ptr<>` represents a resource that is owned by a single owner. By copying it (the pointer) multiple owners would be present. Because of that **`unique_ptr` is not copyable**.

Having said all of it, you can only use the `T&&` overload.

`createPtr()` returns `std::unique_ptr<int>`, but as this is a temporary result (function return value) it is considered a rvalue reference (implicitly). That is why this can be used.

`ptr` is just a `std::unique_ptr<int>` which is a lvalue reference (no matter if you put && next to it, as **named** rvalues are still treated as lvalues). Lvalue is never implicitly converted to rvalue (completely unsafe). But you can basically tell the compiler "Ok, you can take the object I pass you, and I promise I won't expect the argument to be left intact" by using `std::move()`.

Answer (score 17):

Either:

```
vec.push_back(std::move(ptr));
```

Or:

```
vec.emplace_back(createPtr(2));
```

Comment: It solves the problem, but can you please explain the problem?

Comment: @Felics The problem is that `unique_ptr` does not allow copy construction, so trying to `push_back` the `ptr` fails because it attempts to invoke the copy constructor. The move constructor, however, is accessible, and both of Kerrek's  solutions call that instead of the copy constructor.

Comment: @Praetorian What about `emplace_back`?

Comment: @David Same deal, `createPtr` returns a `unique_ptr` by value and `emplace_back` will attempt to call a `unique_ptr` constructor with this argument. The matching constructor is the move constructor.

Comment: @David emplace_back means, create inplace.No copy or move is done for the following. `vec.emplace_back(new int(34))` The value is inplace constructed in the vector

Comment: @David: `emplace`-like functions allow for *explicit* conversions and constructions.

Answer (score 4):

You have a `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = createPtr(2);
```

Now you put a copy of it in the vector:

```
vec.push_back(ptr);
```

Now you have two `unique_ptr`s with the same value.  If that was allowed it would not be unique.