# c++ no matching function for call to vector push_back

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Service> > m_vec;
```

I can run push_back like this:

```
m_vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Service>());
```

But when I run it like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Service> pt = std::make_unique<Service>();
m_vec.push_back(pt);
```

I got error `no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Service> >::push_back(std::unique_ptr<Service>&)`

Does `&` mean that I'm pushing a reference to the vector? If so, why can't I push a reference?

Comment: Your second example tries to make a *copy* of `pt`, which isn't going to work as `unique_ptr`'s copy constructor is deleted.

Comment: Another duplicate: [What is the correct usage of std::unique_ptr while pushing into std::vector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14484183/514235).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) couldn't be copied, only can be moved.

> The class satisfies the requirements of MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable, but not the requirements of either CopyConstructible or CopyAssignable.

`std::make_unique<Service>()` is a temporary variable and could be taken as rvalue and to be moved, but you can not do the same thing with a named variable. You can use [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move):

> `std::move` is used to indicate that an object t may be "moved from"

Such as,

```
m_vec.push_back(std::move(pt));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, if I call move, do I still be able to reuse pt? Or it doesn't exist any more?

Comment: @user4016367 It dpends on what do you mean "reuse pt", after moved, the ownership has been transfered from `pt` to the element of `m_vec`, it doesn't own anything.

Comment: I want m_vec also keep the ownership, how to do it?

Comment: @user4016367 You couldn't, `unique_ptr` is unique, the ownership couldn't be shared. You might want `shared_ptr`, which retains shared ownership of an object through a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

what you want is

```
std::unique_ptr<Service> pt = std::make_unique<Service>();
m_vec.emplace_back(std::move(pt));
```

you cannot copy `unique_ptr`, since they are unique. you can create one and then *move* it around. `emplace_back` will make sure that no temporeries are made, and the element is constructed in-place(without copies, temporeries etc.)