# Unique pointer to Base class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overloading, unique-ptr

I have two classes, `Base` which contains virtual method and `D` which contains overload that method. I want to create a variable with `Base` type, than pass there class `D` which inherits class `Base`. It's my implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>


class Base {
public:
  virtual void bar() { std::cout << "B::bar\n"; }
  //virtual ~Base() = default;
};

typedef Base* Maker();
Maker* arr[10];

class D : Base
{
public:
    D() { std::cout << "D::D\n";  }
    ~D() { std::cout << "D::~D\n";  }
    void bar() override { std::cout << "D::bar\n";  }
};

template <class T>
Base* make(){
    return new T;
}

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<Base> p1(new D);
  p1->bar();

  //arr[0] = make<D>();

  return 0;
}
```

Btw, it's working with structs, but when I try to implement that though classes I'll get error.

Comment: `struct`s _are_ classes! Did you get your access levels wrong?

Comment: Yes, I did `: Base`, when I should use `: public Base`, since I need public elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`D` inherits from `B` privately. Therefore, `D*` is not convertible to `B*`. You likely want `class D : public Base { ... };`

Comment: Yes, I changed it, it's working. However, when I try to do something like this: 
`D *d1 = new D();`
`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> object;`
`object.push_back(d1);`
I'll get error... Can I use `std::unique_ptr` in `std::vector`?

Comment: Make it `object.emplace_back(d1);`

Comment: @lostsky25 yes, you can use `unique_ptr` in a `vector`. Storing smart pointers in containers is one of the main reasons why `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` and move semantics were invented, since `auto_ptr` can't be used in containers

Comment: @IgorTandetnik note that `object.emplace_back(d1);` will leak `d1` if `emplace_back()` throws. It would be safer to wrap `d1` in a `unique_ptr` first and then move that into the vector. [What is the correct usage of std::unique_ptr while pushing into std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484183/)

Answer (score 1):

The compilation error has two reasons, and both must be fixed.

```
class D : Base
```

`Base` is privately inherited, so only members of `D` can convert a pointer to `D` to a pointer to `B`, you must inherit publicly:

```
class D : public Base
```

Second problem is here:

```
typedef Base* Maker();

Maker* arr[10];

// ...

arr[0] = make<D>();
```

`arr` is an array of function pointers. "Make()" is an expression that evaluates to a function call that returns a `Base *`. Assigning a `Base *` to some function pointer doesn't make any sense, whatsoever. You meant:

```
arr[0] = &make<D>;
```

With both fixes, the shown code compiles.

Comment: Try to uncomment the line that's commented out only because it causes a compilation error (that's the subject matter of the question), and try again.

Comment: _"Btw, it's working with structs"_ Seems the commented out line is _not_ part of the question being presented to us today.